# NodeJS : Why are module errors silent?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have 2 files :

- index.js
- lib/templating.js

In index.js, I include the other file with:

```
const templating = require('./lib/templating');
```

And in the templating file, I am exporting my function with:

```
module.exports = {
    renderNode: function()
```

However, the issue I get is that any error that happens inside the templating file shows up in my console. The application just silently stops.

When an error happens inside index.js, it shows up perfectly.

I guess there is some obvious option or node config that I don't know...?

Comment: I assume you are not in strict mode? WHen you are not in strict mode, some operations may silently fail and you will not know, good practice is to always use strict mode.

Comment: Good point, thanks for pointing it. However, it didn't change my issue.
For example, I used (on purpose) a undefined variable inside my templating file : no error displayed.